# RMarkdown Won't Knit ! Package array Error: Illegal pream-token (e): `c' used

Tags: r, r-markdown

I've been trying to knit my RMarkdown file and keep getting the below error. I've tried all the debugging at https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/ and am still getting the error.

I was unable to find any missing LaTeX packages from the error log test.log.
! Package array Error:  Illegal pream-token (e): `c' used.

Error: LaTeX failed to compile test.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See test.log for more info.

Here is the file I'm trying to knot

````
    title: "test"
output:
  pdf_document: default
  html_document: default
---
```{r, include=FALSE}
options(tinytex.verbose = TRUE)
```

```{r echo=FALSE, message=FALSE,warning=FALSE}

library(socviz)
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)
library(anytime)
library(kableExtra)
library(lubridate)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
library(scales)
```

#Elementary Education PRAXIS II Scores
###2019-2020

##Overall PRAXIS II Scores

Overall PRAXIS II scores for students passing Elementary Education subtests in each completion year cohort.
Students are required to pass all four subject tests in order to be licensed in Elementary Education.

```{r echo=FALSE, message=FALSE} 

library(readxl)
setwd("C:/Users/asimpfen/Desktop/Praxis")

PRAXIS_201819_UVM_Var_NetID <- read_excel("C:/Users/asimpfen/Desktop/Praxis/PRAXIS 201819-UVM Var.  NetID.xlsx")
PRAXIS_201920_UVM_Var_NetID <- read_excel("C:/Users/asimpfen/Desktop/Praxis/PRAXIS 201920-UVM Var.  NetID.xlsx")
Sub_test_codes <- read_excel("C:/Users/asimpfen/Desktop/Praxis/Sub test codes.xlsx")

#merge praxis scores together
PRAXIS_All<-rbind(PRAXIS_201819_UVM_Var_NetID,PRAXIS_201920_UVM_Var_NetID)

#select ELED students only
ELED<-filter(PRAXIS_All,UG_Degree_Major=="ELK6",Pass___Not_Pass == "Passed")

#remove PRAXIS Core scores
ELED<-ELED[(ELED$Test_Name =='5002 Elem Ed: MS Reading & Language Arts Subtest'|ELED$Test_Name =='5003 Elem Ed: MS Mathematics Subtest'|ELED$Test_Name=='5004 Elem Ed: MS Social Studies Subtest'|
             ELED$Test_Name =='5005 Elem Ed: MS Science Subtest'),]

#change test date to correct format
ELED$Test_Date<-anytime(ELED$Test_Date)

#create UVM licensure requirement variable
ELED<-ELED%>%mutate(UVM_Lic_Rec=case_when(
              (.$UG_Degree_Term==201801 & .$Test_Date<=as.POSIXct('2019-05-30')~"2018"),
              (.$UG_Degree_Term==201806 & .$Test_Date<=as.POSIXct('2019-08-31')~"2019"),
              (.$UG_Degree_Term==201809 & .$Test_Date<=as.POSIXct('2019-12-31')~"2019"),#this worked
              (.$UG_Degree_Term==201901 & .$Test_Date<=as.POSIXct('2020-05-30')~"2019"),
              (.$UG_Degree_Term==201906 & .$Test_Date<=as.POSIXct('2020-08-31')~"2019"),
              (.$UG_Degree_Term==201909 & .$Test_Date<=as.POSIXct('2020-12-31')~"2020"),
              (.$UG_Degree_Term==202001 & .$Test_Date<=as.POSIXct('2021-05-30')~"2020"),
              (.$UG_Degree_Term==202006 & .$Test_Date<=as.POSIXct('2021-08-31')~"2020"),TRUE~'No Lic'))

#fix specific instances where students were granted exemption to one year rule
ELED$UVM_Lic_Rec[ELED$netid=='lhandy' & ELED$Test_Name=='5005 Elem Ed: MS Science Subtest']<-'2020'
ELED$UVM_Lic_Rec[ELED$netid=='lhandy' & ELED$Test_Name=='5004 Elem Ed: MS Social Studies Subtest']<-'2020'

#create CAEP completer variable year
ELED$CAEP_Comp_Yr<-with(ELED,
  ifelse(UVM_Lic_Rec==2018 & Test_Date<=as.POSIXct("2018-08-31"),'2018',
  ifelse(UVM_Lic_Rec==2018 & Test_Date<=as.POSIXct("2019-08-31"),'2019',
  ifelse(UVM_Lic_Rec==2019 & Test_Date<=as.POSIXct("2019-08-31"),'2019',
  ifelse(UVM_Lic_Rec==2019 & Test_Date<=as.POSIXct("2020-08-31"),'2020',
  ifelse(UVM_Lic_Rec==2020 & Test_Date<=as.POSIXct("2020-08-31"),'2020',
  ifelse(UVM_Lic_Rec==2020 & Test_Date<=as.POSIXct("2021-08-31"),'2021',NA)))))))

ELED1<-select(ELED,netid,UG_Degree_Year,UG_Degree_Term,Test_Date,Test_Name,Score,CAEP_Comp_Yr,UVM_Lic_Rec)

#pivot data so that there the individual ELED tests are each a column for CAEP Completion
test1<-pivot_wider(ELED1,id_cols = netid ,names_from = c(Test_Name,CAEP_Comp_Yr),values_from = Score, values_fn = max)
CAEP<-pivot_wider(ELED,id_cols = netid ,names_from = Test_Name,values_from = CAEP_Comp_Yr, values_fn = max)

#drop students who have not passed all four exams
CAEP<-CAEP[complete.cases(CAEP[,2:5]),]

#select max value for final CAEP completion year
CAEP$CAEP_Comp_Final<-pmax(CAEP$`5002 Elem Ed: MS Reading & Language Arts Subtest`,CAEP$`5003 Elem Ed: MS Mathematics Subtest`,CAEP$`5004 Elem Ed: MS Social Studies Subtest`,CAEP$`5005 Elem Ed: MS Science Subtest`)

#merge back into main CAEP data set
ELED<-merge(x=ELED,CAEP[,c("netid","CAEP_Comp_Final")],by="netid",all.x = TRUE)

#pivot data so that there the individual ELED tests are each a column for ROPA/Title II Completion
test1<-pivot_wider(ELED1,id_cols = netid ,names_from = c(Test_Name,CAEP_Comp_Yr),values_from = Score, values_fn = max)
ROPA<-pivot_wider(ELED,id_cols = netid ,names_from = Test_Name,values_from = UVM_Lic_Rec, values_fn = max)

#drop students who have not passed all four exams
ROPA<-ROPA[complete.cases(ROPA[,2:5]),]

#remove those who did not receive their license
test3<-ROPA%>%
  filter_all(all_vars(!grepl('No Lic',.)))

#select max value for final CAEP completion year
ROPA$ROPA_Comp_Final<-pmax(ROPA$`5002 Elem Ed: MS Reading & Language Arts Subtest`,ROPA$`5003 Elem Ed: MS Mathematics Subtest`,ROPA$`5004 Elem Ed: MS Social Studies Subtest`,ROPA$`5005 Elem Ed: MS Science Subtest`)

#merge back into main CAEP data set
ELED<-merge(x=ELED,ROPA[,c("netid","ROPA_Comp_Final")],by="netid",all.x = TRUE)

#remove ELED students who have not completed or are outside the desired range
ELED<-ELED[!is.na(ELED$CAEP_Comp_Final),]

#change Score to numeric value
ELED$Score<-as.numeric(ELED$Score)

#create tables
ELED_Sum<-ELED%>%
  group_by(Test_Name,CAEP_Comp_Final)%>%
  summarize(N=n())

ELED_Score<-ELED%>%
  group_by(Test_Name,CAEP_Comp_Final)%>%
  summarize(N=n(),Avg=mean(Score,round(2)))
  
ELED_Score1<-pivot_wider(ELED_Score,id_cols = CAEP_Comp_Final ,names_from = Test_Name,values_from = Avg)

#Rename completion year
colnames(ELED_Score1)[colnames(ELED_Score1)=='CAEP_Comp_Final']<-'Completion Year'

kbl(ELED_Score1)%>%
  kable_classic()%>%
  row_spec(0,bold = TRUE,align = 'center')%>%
  row_spec(1:2,align = 'center')%>%
  add_header_above(c("","Overall Subject Test Scores"=4))

```
````

Comment: `! Package array Error: Illegal pream-token (e): \`c' used.` is an error of `tabular` package [see here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110333/illegal-pream-token-in-tabular). I suspect that the error would disappear when you comment out the five-line code  `kbl(ELED_Score1)%>%...`. If so, knit the Rmd file again uncommenting the  `kbl(ELED_Score1)%>%...` and enabling [keep tex option](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/pdf-document.html#keeping-intermediate-tex), and add the `tabular` code from `.tex` file to this post. We can check if the tabular command has any illegal parameter.